# How to replace only current wrong character on keyup for regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui, replace

I wish to replace any character not in the passport format(A9999999) from my input text. I have written the following ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0zf6h5sc/)):

HTML

```html
Doc Type <input id='docType' value = 'PASS'/> <br>
Doc ID <input id='docId'/>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var docTypeVal = $("#docType").val();
    $('#docId').keyup(function() {
        if(docTypeVal == "PASS") {
            var $th = $(this);
            $th.attr("maxlength","8");

            if($th.val().length <= 1) {
                $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, function(str) { 
                    alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use correct format.'); 
                    return ''; 
                })
            }
            else if($th.val().length <= 8 && $th.val().length > 1) {
                $th.val().replace(/^(?!.*^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9]){7}$)/, function(str) { 
                    alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use correct format.'); 
                    return ''; 
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However, firstly, this doesn't replace any characters (wrong/right). Secondly, it gives the alert the moment I enter 2nd character onwards. It should accept the 1st char if it is alphabet (replace otherwise), from 2nd till 8th char it should accept only numbers (replace otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

You can test this with 1 Regular Expression.

`/^[a-z]?\d{0,7}$/i`

This pattern will look `A9` up to `A9999999`. It will fail on `AA` or `99`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/awL0onjg/20/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var docTypeVal = $("#docType").val();
  $('#docId').keyup(function(e) {
    var exc = [
      11, // Tab
      127, // Del
    ];
    if (exc.indexOf(e.which) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
    var term = $(this).val();
    var re = /^[a-z]?\d{0,7}$/i;

    console.log("Testing:", term, re.test(term));
    if (re.test(term)) {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
      return true;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
    }
  });
});
```

Consider using `.keydown()` if you want to prevent the User from typing outside of that pattern. [See More](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0zf6h5sc/4/)

Referred the JS of [Twisty's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872143/how-to-replace-only-current-wrong-character-on-keyup-for-regex/58873202#58873202) and realized it should be as shown below:

```
if(docTypeVal == "PASS") {
  $(this).attr("maxlength","8");
  var term = $(this).val();
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{0,7}$/i;
  if (re.test(term)) {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
      return true;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
      $(this).val(term.replace(term.charAt(term.length-1), 
      function(str) { 
      alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use correct format.'); 
      return ''; 
    }));
    return false;
   }
 }
```